# Bug in ExportString with Associations as ExpressionML?

Tags: bugs, associations

**Bug present in 10.0.2 or earlier, and fixed in 10.4**

---

If I try to export this toy code as `ExpressionML` or just `XML`:

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3, Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}]};
str1 = ExportString[data1, "ExpressionML"];
ImportString[str1]
```

I have no problem. Executing it, I get as expected:

[image: ok example]

But if I try to export some expression containing as `Association` like this:

```
data2 = {1, 2, 3, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 5|>};
str2 = ExportString[data2, "ExpressionML"];
(*ImportString[str2]*)
```

I get:

[image]

So, I can't export `Associations`. This is a bug no? Tested in Mathematia 10.0.2 for MAC.

**UPDATE**

A very clumsy workaround that I did was:

```
data3={1,2,3,<|"a"-> 4,"b"-> 5,"c"-><|"a"-> 4,"b"-> 5|>|>};
str3=ExportString[data3/.Association-> AssociationTemp,"ExpressionML"];
ImportString[str3]/.AssociationTemp-> Association
```

Note that for nested `Associations`, `Replace` works properly just from V10.0.2

Comment: Looks like a bug indeed. A job for support@wolfram.com I'd say.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I sent a formal report about it.

Comment: What are you using ExpressionML for?

Comment: @Szabolcs to exchange code using the web between two Mathematicas. I did a rest service using WebMathematica, that another Mathematica can read.

Comment: @Murta Why is it necessary to use XML instead of standard Mathematica notation?  I don't know much about REST.  I would have assumed that an XML representation of expressions is useful if one needs to dissect them using a program other than Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs, do you have a suggestion of secure way to do that? Pass expression in FullForm as string maybe?

Comment: @Murta Yes, to transfer expressions between two Mathematica kernels, I would have simply converted them to a string: `ToString` or even better, `Compress`.  But once again: I'm not even sure what REST is precisely, so I really don't know what its constraints are :)  Note: there are some edge cases that are not properly handled when converting to strings and back.  The *only* export format that is fully robust in this way is MX, I believe.  But that's not cross platform and not a good choice for what you are doing.

Comment: @Szabolcs, worked very nice!.. Tks, much better.

Comment: @Murta: would you mind to share *what* exactly works much better :-). Anyway I agree that this is a bug and `ToString` and `Compress` are good candidates for the use case you mentioned. If you mention REST and ever would want to access the service with something that is not Mathematica another alternative format that comes to mind is JSON which I think should play well with `Associations` (but probably not with more involved expressions like `Graphics`...)

Comment: @AlbertRetey at the time of this question, I was making some experiments transferring information between webMathematica servers. So I user expStr = ToString@FullForm[someExpression] to create the expression in string format, send it over Rest, and ToExpression@expStr in the other side to transform it back into  Mathematica code.

Comment: thanks for the information, @Murta. Just realized that the question was that old and just edited today...

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed as of version 10.4.0.

```
data2 = {1, 2, 3, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 5|>};
str2 = ExportString[data2, "ExpressionML"];
ImportString[str2]

(* {1, 2, 3, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 5|>} *)
```